# My content is disappearing completely

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm not sure why my content is disappearing almost completely, the navbar is still intact, but it won't open, the text in the navbar won't center, the paragraphs aren't responsive, my subscribe button isn't aligned. I'm extremely frustrated and I've been working on this site for a couple of weeks already. Can someone please help me with this. This is a link to the site: http://bit.ly/1kPKVzR Thanks in advance. This is the code for one of the pages in the site...

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="...">
    <meta name="author" content="...">

    <title>...</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon" />
    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/full.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="css/customstyle.css" rel="stylesheet">    
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
<style type="text/css">

::-moz-selection { 
    color:#fff;
    background-color:rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.3); 
}
::selection { 
    color:#fff;
    background-color:rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.3); 
}

.navbar  {
    color:#000000;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0);
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0);
}
.logo{
    display:inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left:40%;
    font-size: 20px;

    font: 80px "munich", Sans-serf, Ariel;
    margin-top: 60px;
}

.logo a:focus, .logo a:hover{
    -webkit-transition:1s;
    color:#999999;
        text-decoration: none;
}
.logo li a:focus, .logo li a:hover{
    -webkit-transition:1s;
    color:#000000;
}
@font-face{
    font-family:"munich";
    src:url("munich.ttf") format("truetype");
}

.starter-template img{
    width:450px;
    height:450px;
    margin: 40px 100px auto;
}
audio{
   width:200px;
 }

.starter-template .pull-right{
position:absolute;

}

.starter-template img{
    width:450px;
    height:450px;
    margin:20px 100px auto;
}

#albumlinks{    

    margin-top:440px;
    margin-right: -40em; 

}
#signup{
    position: absolute; right: -5000px;
}
#mc_embed_signup{
  background:none; font:14px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;  margin:500px;padding:0;
}


/**************** @media screen ********************/

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {


    #albumlinks .clear-fix .pull-right{
    width:5em;
    height:4em;
  }
 }
.navbar-default{
        background-color: rgba(245, 245, 245,  0.1);

}
 .navbar-nav{
  margin-top: -20px;
 }

</style>
</head>
<body>        
<div class="logo">
    <p><a href="index.html">...</a></p>
    </div>
      <!-- Navigation -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>

                </div>

               <div class="collapse navbar-collapse pull-right" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                       <li>
                            <a href="#">Bio</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Lessons</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Shows</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Music</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.container -->
        </nav>
      <div class="clearfix">
    <div class="container">
          <div class="pull-left">
          <img src="../images/piano-1599x1066.jpg"/>
    </div>



    <p class="lead pull-right ">...</p> 



        </div>

    </div>

        <footer class="navbar-fixed-bottom ">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse pull-right" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse pull-right" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <div class="navbar-text pull-right">
                <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></a>
                <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></i></a>
                <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-soundcloud fa-2x"></i></a>
                </div>

                <p class="pull-right">...</p>
                </div>
                </div>
    </footer>


       <!-- jQuery -->
            <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

            <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
            <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </body>
```

Comment: Erica, why did you put everything inside navbar..??  Do you have any spec of the UI about what is it that you wish to achieve...??

Comment: Did you have a look at the developer console?  There's something wrong with jQuery.... Please post your `<head>` section too

Comment: I added the <head> section. I put my CSS in the same file in order to try to debug, and make it bit easier to see exactly where everything is- if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error that says "Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher"

So you need to change the JQuery that is loaded to a newer version.
Where yours says

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
```

change it to

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery and Bootstrap .js files are not linked properly.

Once script is working, add css to `.navbar-toggle .icon-bar` and navbar.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your site and press Ctrl+Shift+I if you are using chrome otherwise right click and choose inspect element. Doing this will bring up the dev tools and most importantly the console.

Looking there we can see that there are errors about JQuery not being loaded.
You can include it in your site by adding the below to the  section of your site.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

Or alternatively fix the link to your jQuery - http://ericarodriguez.me/jarodkashkin/js/jquery.js
If you click that link you will see that the file does not exist

Comment: Thanks for your help. I should note that I created a new template and added this code now it works perfectly!